# Magento 2: getPost and getPostValue methods on the request object

Tags: magento2, http-request

I see that everywhere where the request is involved in Magento 2, the request is an implementation of `\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface`.
This interface does not contain the methods `getPost` (used in `\Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Widget\CategoriesJson`) and `getPostValue` (used in `\Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Save`) but they are still called.
Is it OK to assume that these methods are always going to be there for http requests?
or should I use something else in my modules to get the `$_POST` data?

Comment: I feel that half a year later, with Magento 2.1, this situation still hasn't improved at all :-(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it OK to assume that these methods are always going to be there for http requests?

Don't think so. They're breaking their own class contract. As you can imagine, that's not OOP-ish at all.

As per the usual recommendation, I would stay away from using anything that's *not* declared in `Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface` because a) you'll make Liskov happy and because b) they'll soon realise the problem and fix it (hopefully), thus breaking your code (or not; but if they do, they're justified: you were not using the API contract, right?).

If they *won't* fix it, they'll have a very capable API implementation (i.e. `Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http`) which nobody will *really* use.

Always stay within the contract!

Comment: This looks like a good approach in an ideal world. Unfortunately I found no other way to get the post data with methods only from the `RequestInterface`. But what you are saying sounds resonable. I will avoid as much as possible these methods.

Comment: It looks like they're aware. Only recently: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/1675

Comment: An easy way to check whether or not those are available to you would be to do an `if($this->getRequest() instanceof \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http) {` - if that check passes, you can use those parameters!

Answer (score 5):

`getPostValue()` is written in

`lib\internal\Magento\Framework\HTTP\PhpEnvironment\Request.php`

```
 /**
     * Retrieve POST parameters
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @param mixed $default
     * @return mixed|ParametersInterface
     */
    public function getPostValue($name = null, $default = null)
    {
        $post = $this->getPost($name, $default);
        if ($post instanceof ParametersInterface) {
            return $post->toArray();
        }
        return $post;
    }
```

then It get the `getPost` value from

`vendor\zendframework\zend-http\src\Request.php`

```
public function getPost($name = null, $default = null)
    {
        if ($this->postParams === null) {
            $this->postParams = new Parameters();
        }

        if ($name === null) {
            return $this->postParams;
        }

        return $this->postParams->get($name, $default);
    }
```

Hope you will get atleast some hint.

---

And yes you can use

```
$post = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
```

To get `post` value,,you can also check `Contact` module to get some hint

Comment: Thanks for the "code hunt". But that was not my question. I already found the definition. That's why I asked *"are always going to be there for http requests?"*. My question is "Is it safe to use these methods even if they are not in the RequestInterface?" and this is used everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

**To get Post data in controller you need to use following in your execute function.**

```
public function execute(){
    $post = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($post);
    exit; }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 2.1, if we get the request object by calling `$this->getRequest()`, it will return `Magento\Framework\App\Request` which is extend `Magento\Framework\HTTP\PhpEnvironment\Request`. this is why the method getPostValue can be called.

I got the problem when I try to create a unit test for my controller which call the getPostValue. As the getPostValue is not defined in the RequestInterface, Instead of creating a mock object for RequestInterface directly, we create the mock object for `Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http`.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it OK to assume that these methods are always going to be there for http requests?

No.

The method will be changed in the future version if it is not in the interface. We should use the methods in the interface as much as possible. Because of API contract, existing methods in API will not be changed except in major version upgrades.

> Should I use something else in my modules to get the $_POST data?

Yes.

In the interface `Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface`, the method `getParams()` could get the post data array, the method `getParam($key, $defaultValue = null)` could get the specific data in post.